# Pandas 2-Column Dataframe Categorical Rows

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing two columns, values and categories.  I need to translate the dataframe to have one row per value, with 1 or 0 for that values relevant categories.

So from this:

```
+--------+--------------+
| value  |   category   |
+--------+--------------+ 
|   1    |      32      |
|   1    |      33      |
|   1    |      34      |
|   1    |      35      |
|   2    |      32      |
|  ...   |      ...     |
+--------+--------------+
```

To this:

```
+--------+----+----+----+----+
| value  | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35 |
+--------+----+----+----+----+
|   1    |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |
|   2    |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |
+--------+----+----+----+----+
```

I've tried to go about this by using nested loops but it is too slow.  Is there a better way?

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df.value, df.category).clip(upper=1)` Or `pivot`.

Comment: I don't think this works.  Care to elaborate on pivot?

Comment: Probably not worth it, because if `crosstab` is somehow not working (though it truly reproduces your expected output) then every other solution I'd propose would equally fail since they are all just 10 different ways to do the exact same thing. just some use `groupby`, others `pivot` others `get_dummies` In the end all the same.

Comment: That being said, if somehow that `crosstab` isn't truly working could you provide a [mcve] that would illustrate that it's not the desired solution?

Answer (score 0):

this should work, take `@ALollz` suggestion and reset index.

```
import pandas as pd
raw_data = {'value':      [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
            'category':     [32, 33, 34, 35, 36]}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
df = pd.crosstab(df.value, df.category).clip(upper=1)
df.reset_index(drop=True)
```